# Should I use an individual sprite for each page or a single sprite for all pages?

Tags: html, css

I have many pages in website and there are some pages that have common images plus individual images, so should i make a single sprite for all pages and use across or every page should have their own sprite

Comment: Where do sprites fit in here? Just use a common image across all pages and each individual image individually.

Comment: You would need to elaborate on the images you are trying to use.  If we are talking small icons that will all be placed into a single image sprite and save lots of http requests then there is some value in doing so even if all icons will not be used on all pages.  The entire sprite would be cached upon the first load and therefore subsequent pages wouldn't incur much of a hit.

Comment: include your current sprite sheet and some examples of what you want to add please - there is a lot of subjectiveness for this type of question but we can discuss guidelines with enough specifics to go on.

Comment: in my case there are approx 20 icons in common and 10 icons for each page specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial goal should be the least number of requests and therefore conceptual files.  A single sprite file will be one request which will then be cached which would equal no requests for subsequent pages.  Therefore you should use as few sprite files *site-wide* as possible.

The only other factor is file size.  If your sprite files begin to get large, then you may want to split them up to take advantage of multiple concurrent transfers (normally 2).  Your sprite files should usually be small enough that this isn't an issue, since sprites normally contain smaller visual elements (and if this is a concern you should do some more serious research).

If you have page-specific small elements they should be in a consolidated site wide sprite.  If they have consequential size then you should decide based on how large the images are vs. how likely that page is to be viewed by any given site visitor.